# What is $13^{498}$ (mod $997$)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to determine $$13^{498} \pmod{997}$$

I know that it can only be $1$ or $-1$. But I don't quite know which. How can I decide?

Comment: Do you mean 498 instead of 488 as that is 1 or -1 or maybe even 977 instead of 997

Comment: @JohnMarty- I'm sorry. I mean 498 and 997

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde - I think this is different as it is very specifically looking at what $x^{p-1/2}$ can be.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) to find
$$
13^{498}\equiv\left(\frac{13}{997}\right)=\left(\frac{997}{13}\right)=\left(\frac9{13}\right)=1
$$